# Definition of a `flatten' map

Tags: category-theory

In many programming languages (e.g. Mathematica), there are `flatten' functions, which take nested lists as inputs, and output their non-nested versions. For instance, we have

$$
\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}\mapsto \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.
$$

I'd like to formally define this map, preferably in categorical terms. For my purposes, I only need to define a map which takes a class of classes to a class. For instance, if $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ are sets, I want a map that does the following:

$$
\{\{\{A_1\},\{A_2\}\},\{\{A_3\},\{A_4\}\}\}\mapsto \{A_1,\dots, A_4\}
$$

Here is my attempt:

Define the category $\textbf{Cl}_1$ of $1$-classes as the category whose objects are classes of the form
$$
\mathcal{X}=\{X\in\textbf{Set}\mid P(X)\},
$$
where $P$ is a property shared by all the elements of $\mathcal{X}$. Arrows in this category are given by inclusions (in other words, this is a poset category, where the objects are $1$-classes). Now, for $k>1$, define the category $\textbf{Cl}_k$ recursively as the category whose objects are of the form
$$
\mathfrak{X}=\{\mathcal{X}\in\textbf{Cl}_{k-1}\mid P(\mathfrak{X})\},
$$
with inclusions as its arrows. Let $\textbf{Cl}_0:=\textbf{Set}$, and define, for all $k>1$,
$$
\mathsf{flat}_k: \textbf{Cl}_k\longrightarrow \textbf{Cl}_{k-1}::\mathfrak{X}\longmapsto\{X\in\textbf{Cl}_{k-2}\mid \exists \mathcal{X}\in\mathfrak{X}:X\in \mathcal{X}\},
$$ 
which is clearly a functor. Finally, let
$$
\mathsf{Flatten}_k: \textbf{Cl}_k\longrightarrow \textbf{Cl}_1
$$ 
be defined by $\mathsf{Flatten}_k=\mathsf{flat}_2\circ\mathsf{flat}_3\circ\cdots\circ\mathsf{flat}_{k-1}\circ\mathsf{flat}_k$.

Is this definition problematic? The reason why I'm asking is that I'm not very familiar with non-small categories and I know one has to be careful with many details. I actually thought about defining my map as a natural transformation between functors of the form $[k]\mapsto \textbf{Cl}_k$, for $[k]\in\Delta$, but this would require the definition of the category of all categories, which is problematic.

Any help or reference suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Don't you mean just the union?

Comment: I don't see how the union would help me here. The union is a binary operation (it requires two sets as inputs). Also, if I take $\mathcal{X}:=\{\{A\},\{B\}\}$ and I take the unions of all the elements of $\mathcal{X}$, I obtain $\{\{A,B\}\}$, which is not what I want.

Comment: It looks like he wants to keep unioning recursively until there are no more members that are sets?

Comment: Just to be clear, if the end result is of the form $\{\{\{\dots\{ A_1,\dots, A_n\}\dots\}\}\}$, it is not good, as it would still constitute a $k$-class, with $k>1$.

Comment: No, the union is an unary operation. Taking a set (of sets) and returning the union of the elements.

Comment: I have never seen the union operation defined as a unary operation, but I trust you! In this case, could you please give me its definition? (I don't see how it would solve the problem I mentioned in my second comment though)

Comment: If I use the union as you suggested, I guess my new question would be: how to define a map that acts as follows: $\{\{\{\dots\{A_1,\dots, A_n\}\dots\}\}\}\mapsto \{A_1,\dots A_n\}$?

Comment: @John Look at the page for the [union axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union) - it's the thing denoted "$\bigcup A$."

Comment: Ok, now I understand! Sorry, I'm not a set theorist, I didn't know about this. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: From a category-theoretic perspective, you're dealing with *universes* -- i.e. this ZFC-style notion of set gets expressed by defining a class $\mathbf{Ele} = \{ (x, y) \mid x \in \mathbf{Set}, y \in x \} $, and the projection $\pi : \mathbf{Ele} \to \mathbf{Set}$ onto the first coordinate, and it is through taking the inverse image under $\pi$ that we can give meaning to the notion that an "element" of $\mathbf{Set}$ can itself have elements.

Comment: Universes are an *extremely* cumbersome notion of "set" to work with category theoretically; this is almost surely not how you want to tackle the issue. You probably want to do something like look at the union operator $\mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}X \to \mathcal{P}X$ and its iterates that you can find in a topos, or maybe you want to do something related to inductive types to express what something like $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$ actually means.

Comment: Incidentally, all of your examples have constant depth; are you forgetting about things like $\{\{1,2\}, 3 \}$, or are those really excluded from whatever problem you're studying?

Comment: (really, you probably ask a question about your actual purposes, rather than the idea you had to try and achieve those purposes)

Comment: @Hurkyl Thanks a lot for your comments! Yes, in my case all the classes have constant depth, but I'm curious about the general case as well. I'm sorry I haven't specified my actual purposes, but it would have been impossible to summarize them in such a short space. I'm working on a cohomological characterization of non-locality and contextuality in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Have you thought about the relation of this construction with the multiplication of the free-monoid / forgetful [monad](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/basics-of-haskell/13-the-list-monad)?